# Can't create Database Model using 'ADO.NET Entity Data Model': missing assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm fallowing this tutorial: [Microsoft's tutorial for Entity Framework, Database first.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/workflows/database-first). However, once I get to the part where I need to add an 'ADO.NET Entity Data Model', it shows me this error window: [image]

I've added the fallowing dependencies:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.5">
```

I'm also using .NET 5.

I can't understand why it isn't working. The instructor of video in the tutorial page adds it effordlessly, and doesn't even mention dependencies or assemblies.

Comment: Entity Framework **Core** doesn't support creating an entity data model (`.edmx` file) anymore. You need to express your database's tables directly in C# code and create code-based mappings

Comment: You are following a tutorial for the ancient EF6, but working in .NET Core...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that there are many [differences between EF6 and EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/), as @marc_s mentioned in comment, the EDMX file format for models is not supported in EF Core.

[image]

To generate code for DbContext and entity types for your existing database, you can use [Scaffold-DbContext command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext) or [dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold).

Comment: You can check this doc about ["Porting an EF6 EDMX-Based Model to EF Core"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/porting/port-edmx).